# matlab - plot trendline with specific condition(e.g. slope at specific x value, must past through specific point,etc)

Tags: matlab, constraints, curve-fitting

Good day.

I got a scatter plotted in MatLab. I want to plot a trendline of the data on the plot as well. But instead of a normal quadratic curve fitting, I want to constrain the trendline with slope=0 when x=0. How could I achieve that?

And out of curiosity, how to constrain a trendline with must pass through specific point? Just like setting intercept in excel?

And can a trendline have multiple constrain like that I described above?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to fit a quadratic, `a*x^2+b*x+c` to your data, but you want the derivative to be zero somewhere. That is an extra constraint that will relate the variables. The derivative is `2*a*x+b` so for it to be 0 at `x=0`, you need `b=0`. So you are now trying to fit `a*x^2+c` to your data. This is not too difficult,

```
A=[x(:).^2 ones(size(x(:)))];
coeffs=A\y(:);
fittedY=@(x) coeffs(1)*x.^2+coeffs(2)
```

And `fittedY(x)` gives the value of the fitted curve at `x`.

If you want your fit to have a certain value, rather than a certain derivative somewhere, you do a similar thing. Say you want the fit to equal 1 at `x=1`. Then `a+b+c=1`, so set `c=1-b-a` and the function you fit will be `a*x^2+b*x+1-b-a`.

You can use up to three such constraints, however using 3 constraints will (in general) uniquely determine a quadratic function, so there will be no parameters left to fit with.

Comment: What if for a cubic function, I put a constraint such that b=0, will it works if I change to A=[x(:).^3 zeroes(size(x(:))) x(:).^2 ones(sizes(x(:)))] and fittedY=@(x) coeffs(1)*x.^3+coeffs(2)*x+coeffs(3)

Comment: No, if your cubic is `a*x^3+b*x^2+c*x+d` and you want to quadratic term, you'd have `A=[x(:).^3 x(:) ones(size(x(:)))]` and `fittedY=coeffs(1)*x.^3+coeffs(2)*x+coeffs(3)`.

Comment: So for any 0 coefficient terms, no columns of zeroes or whatever should be reserved in matrix A which to be left divided. I got it. Thank you very much.

Comment: Basically you need one column in your A matrix for each unknown variable, so a cubic with one constraint has 3 variables left, so A should have 3 columns, etc.